# Populate textarea if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, auto-populate

I'm using this to populate a textarea with value if a checkbox is checked:

```
$('#checkbox_a').change(function(){
    $("#textarea_b").text("");
    if ($('#checkbox_a').is(':checked')) { 
        $("#textarea_b").text("Yes"); 
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that if a user already inputs something in the textarea, decides to delete his input again and marks the checkbox afterwards it won't get populated anymore.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: You have to use `.val()` to change the contents of a textarea after it has been edited, not `.text()`.

Comment: The problem with .val( ) is that in this case it changes everytime the input if the checkbox is clicked even tho the user already wrote something inside. I only want it to change if there is no input inside the textbox

Comment: Check if the value is empty before replacing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.val()` to change the value of a textarea.

To prevent overwriting the user's input, check if the textarea is empty before replacing it.

```js
$('#checkbox_a').change(function() {
  if ($("#textarea_b").val() == "") {
    if ($('#checkbox_a').is(':checked')) {
      $("#textarea_b").val("Yes");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_a">
<br>
<textarea id="textarea_b"></textarea>
```